# Advantages of different methods of setting server side variables for use in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

A college and I got into a spirited discussion on how to set variables from the server side to the clients side

His solution was straight forward
In Aspx page:

```
<script>
Var sitecorevalue1 = <%=sitecorevalue1onserverside%>
</script>
```

And then in the javascript page just access the variable

I took a different approach

You create one div element with many data- attributes on the aspx side like

```
<div id=”variables” class=”hide” data-one="today" data-two=”mike” data-three=”hello” />
```

You can even wrap that div creation in an IF statement for when the variables may not need to be used or don't exist

Then on the javascript side

```
var variables = $(“#variables”);

if (variables.length) {
    X= variables.data(“one”)
    Y= variables.data(“two”)
    Z= variables.data(“three”)

}
```

The advantages I put forward are

- Not polluting the name space.
- Not having to worry if someone else created the same variable.
- Not having to check if each variable exists (in our case it is all-or-nothing for 15 or so variables).

So am I correct in my approach?

Which approach is the best of the two? Or is there a third option we did not consider?

Comment: I'd say your friend's approach requires a strict naming convention, and immediate rename or use of the variables on client side. However, I prefer that approach, because you can use `json.stringify` to send complicated object or arrays.

Comment: Well instead of a variable look up, you now have a DOM lookup and have to wait for it to be ready to read it. Afraid of globals, than use a name spaced object that has the variables. You way is fine with simple data, but with more complicated things, you need to parse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I prefer your colleague's approach. It's a clear and straight forward assignment of variables.

Due to the fact that the aspx page is server side rendered anyway, at the end that what you see and get on client side is `var sitecorevalue1 = anyValue;`. What's wrong with that?

Your approach is a work around. Actually you are creating a container for transporting data from server side to client side, although the aspx is server side rendered anyway. It's an ineffictive way of transporting values.
And also keep in mind that if you do straight javascript declarations you can do all the things you could normally do in javascript. Especially with complex objects your approach might give you some trouble.
Last but not least, yes, your approach is not polluting the namespace but in exchange it is polluting the html.

Comment: I am absolutely on board with this comment. Defining DOM elements to hold values seems a bit primitive to me and it does pollute the html unnecessarily. However I wouldn't call any of these approaches incorrect. As a matter of fact, your approach may look cleaner in a certain specific occasion.

Comment: Thank you, between this and @epascarello comment about creating a namespace object is the way I will approach it.

Answer (score 1):

Truly best solution would be to fetch the data from a webservice or other endpoint. This may be some work to put together, but becomes very useful. This will also speed up page load, and keep all spaces clean.

Comment: Great suggestion. However I disagree on the fact that this is the 'best' approach. A service does not necessarily improve performance. Also in a case  where values could be cached on the server side itself, making repeated calls to a service may actually degrade performance. Imagine a situation where you a dealing with a large data set. You may still use a service for fetching + processing business logic etc. Therefore I would say making calls to a web service may help based on certain cases but not all cases.

Comment: you would cache/save it locally just as you would while putting it on the page. you can also call it early in page load and async load it so you can load your DOM faster and being init of your page.

Comment: Certain data cannot be fetched from a webservice, like _the webservice's URL_, precisely.